# Calculate amount same Ids within db table

Tags: c#

I have two tables. One `Fruit`, and one `FruitBag`. Where `FruitBag` can contain different `Fruit`'s. I want to calculate amount of same fruits(by given Id).

```
public ActionResult FruitCheck(int Id)
{
    int Amount = db.FruitBag.// check amount same id inside db.Fruit
    ....
}
```

This following code wont work, but it's about what I had in mind so you get an idea what I mean:

```
int Amount = db.FruitBag.Count(c=> c.Fruit.Where(f=> f.Id == Id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly had it:

```
int Amount = db.FruitBag.Sum(fb => fb.Count(f => f.Id == Id));
```

You want to get the count of each fruit bag, and then take the *total* (sum) of those counts

Comment: Ah silly me, your answer is right, but I forgot to mention to read from a specific `FruitBag`. It calculate fruits in EVERY `FruitBags`row, not the current one. My bad for being unclear. Something like: `Amount = db.FruitBag.Where(fb=> fb.Id == FruitBagId).Sum(fb => fb.Fruit.Count(f => f.ID == x.ID))`. But this still calculate from all FruitBags.